# color certain points a different color matrix matplotlib

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I have a matrix I have plotted in matplotlib using `self.ax.imshow(arr,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, interpolation = 'none')` at the moment I they are all the same color. However I have another array which is the same size as the are plotted for the matrix. the array contains numbers from 0 to 1. Each number in this array corresponds to a plot on the matrix.
How can I make it so the array with the numbers 0 to 1 correspond to the color of the plot on the matrix

I have a array `numberlist = [(1,34),(2,35),(5,78) etc]` to 310
I then do

```
data = np.array(number list)
N=data.max()+5
arr=np.ones((N,N),dtype='bool')
arr[data[:,1],data[:,0]]=0
```

then the imshow above

Comment: John, When you say "numbers from 0 to 1" do you mean floats between 0 and 1, or the integers 0 or 1?  i.e., are they binary masks as @tcaswell is thinking?

Comment: Also, when you say "a plot on the matrix" do you mean one pixel, point, or matrix element; or do you mean an actual plot of something else associated with the matrix?

Comment: they are floats, 0.233343, 0.2321241,0.923432 etc.

Comment: Your edit helps. So you do have a binary/boolean matrix, `arr`, but what is the float array?

Comment: I think I figured it out, see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit, I believe you mean this:

- You have one `boolean` array that tells you whether or not a point should be plotted.
- You have a `float` array that tells you what color that point should be, if it's plotted.

I'd like to call these arrays: `arr_bool` and `arr_val`.

Multiply them together and you'll get a float when `True` but a zero when `False`, and we can color using their product:

```
N = 10
arr_bool = np.random.random_integers(0,1,(N,N))
arr_val  = np.random.rand(N,N)
imshow(arr_bool*arr_val, cmap = cm.spectral_r, interpolation = 'nearest')
```

So, if we just plot `arr_bool` it will look like this:
[image: boolean array]
And if we plot just the colors, or `arr_val`:
[image: value array]
Putting them together, `arr_bool * arr_val`:
[image: colored array]

Comment: I am also a soft matter grad student.  Send me an email (see my profile for address), we should chat.

Comment: this is what I want, but at the moment, instead of changing the color of the data I want to plot, it changes the color of the parts that I want white