# color plots different colors on a matrix matplotlib

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

[image: Matrix I have created]

I have a matrix I have plotted in matplotlib using `self.ax.imshow(arr,cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, interpolation = 'none')` As you can see the plots are all the same color. 
How can I make the plots, different colours and not just black

Comment: Change the color map to something that is not grey? An overview of color maps can be found here: http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/#id49

Comment: @Robbert Could you post that comment as an answer with a quick example of how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [color certain points a different color matrix matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343923/color-certain-points-a-different-color-matrix-matplotlib)

Comment: What was wrong with the answer on your previous question?  I suspect you real problem is that your arrays are really binary, on [0, 1] (judging from your plot title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct link to the color maps is: http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/#colormaps
You assign the spring color map like this:

`self.ax.imshow(arr, cmap = plt.cm.spring, interpolation = 'none')`.

@tcaswell is of course correct that if your data is binary the color will be binary as well. The color map gives different colors to different z-values. If you want to give the right bottom part a different color from the left bottom part (or whatever), you'll need a different solution. Something with a scatterplot I guess.

Comment: You could also muck with your data before plotting, ie. `tmp_arr = arr * np.arange(np.prod(arr.shape)).reshape(arr.shape)`, but then the color no longer has physical meaning, which just sits wrong with me.

Comment: It is not so much a different solution as a different question.